# Sonar error - Metric 'test_data' should not be computed by a Sensor

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using Sonar 6.4 with SonarJS 3.1.1 and I have configured Sonar Karma Test report plugin from https://github.com/acwatson/sonar-karma-test-report-plugin to get the test execution results on the Sonar dashboard.

When I trigger an analysis on my Js code, it fails with the following error

Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.2:sonar (default-cli) on project webui-parent: Metric 'test_data' should not be computed by a Sensor -> [Help 1]

Please advise.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In SonarQube 6.2 the way test data is handled was changed.

The most recent release of that plugin is nearly 2 years old (Oct 2015). So it looks like it's not compatible with recent releases on SonarQube.

Comment: Thanks. Got the job done using https://github.com/tornaia/karma-sonarqube-unit-reporter